# Assigning JobObject to process with non-zero session id launched from a SYSTEM service

Tags: c++, windows, service, sessionid, createprocessasuser

I have a Windows SYSTEM service which needs to launch a new process in the context of the logged-in user. Along with this, I need to create a Job for the new process with certain limits.

I am extracting the process token of explorer.exe and duplicating it to create a primary token. I use this token in `CreateProcessAsUser` to create the new process running in the context of the user with a session id which is non-zero. When I assign the Job to this process, `AssignProcessToJobObject` function fails with Access denied error. Specifically, I am not able to set `JOBOBJECT_BASIC_UI_RESTRICTIONS` limits (`JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION` works though).

The process is created as suspended and after assigning the job, I am resuming the thread.

When I use the token of the current process (i.e. SYSTEM service with session id 0) instead of explorer.exe, everything works fine.

I am testing this on Windows 10

Comment: [the process session id (which is taken from your token) must be equal to the job session id](https://pastebin.com/Z5yCuYNg). your `Job->SessionId` is 0 but process have not 0.

Comment: and from documentation [All processes within a job must run within the same session as the job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/jobapi2/nf-jobapi2-assignprocesstojobobject)